# iOS - iCal rRule in a EKEvent recurrence rule

Tags: ios, objective-c, icalendar, rfc2445

I have an `iCal` file with a `rRule`: 
`rRule = "FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20140425T160000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TU,TH";`

I need to put this info in a `EKEvent`:

```
EKEvent *event;
event.recurrenceRules = ...
```

I split the `rRule` and save it in `NSArray`:

```
 NSArray * rules = [evento.rRule componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
 event.recurrenceRules = rules;
```

But an error ocurrs:

```
-[__NSCFString relationForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21283350
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString relationForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21283350'
```

Can you help me?
Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution using the EKRecurrenceRule+RRULE library, it's very easy to use.

The link : https://github.com/jochenschoellig/RRULE-to-EKRecurrenceRule

Example to use:

```
NSString *rfc2445String = @"FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-2"; // The 2nd to last weekday of the month

// Result
EKRecurrenceRule *recurrenceRule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initWithString:rfc2445String];
NSLog(@"%@", recurrenceRule);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you split the string to an array, you get an array of strings. But the `recurrenceRules` property expects an array of `EKRecurrenceRule` objects. You have to parse the strings yourself and transform them into `EKRecurrenceRule` objects. The following method should be used for complex recurrence rules:

```
- (id)initRecurrenceWithFrequency:(EKRecurrenceFrequency)type interval:(NSInteger)interval daysOfTheWeek:(NSArray *)days daysOfTheMonth:(NSArray *)monthDays monthsOfTheYear:(NSArray *)months weeksOfTheYear:(NSArray *)weeksOfTheYear daysOfTheYear:(NSArray *)daysOfTheYear setPositions:(NSArray *)setPositions end:(EKRecurrenceEnd *)end
```

See documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKRecurrenceRuleClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)